# JSON_ENCODE ONLY SHOW ONE RECORD

Tags: php, arrays

hI I'm trying to get a json from my array using

```
json_decode(json_encode($array2, true);
```

but it only returns me one object and if i use the function `Print_tr`, i can see the whole array.

[image]

i only get this

[image]

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Comment: `true` is an option for `json_decode()`, not `json_encode()`.

Comment: You're returning from the function as soon as you find the first element with `tipoProducto_id == 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning from the function as soon as you find the first matching element. If you want multiple elements, you need to push them onto an array, and return when the loop is done.

There's also no need to convert to and from JSON. Just create the array that you want.

```
$array2 = [];
foreach ($result2 as $r) {
    if ($r['tipoProducto_id'] == 1) {
        $array2[] = ['id' => $r['id'], 'marca' => $r['Marca']];
    }
}
return $array2;
```

Comment: thank you very much, your answer extremely helped me and that what it was happening.